# How to solve string templates are not supported by current javascript version

Tags: javascript, mako

I try to use the answer from my previous question

[Enable datatables with custom layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46077418/enable-datatables-with-speial-layout#46077418)

But I get an error message in Pycharm:

"String templates are not supported by current javascript version"

Do you know what I can do about it? If I replace with actual quotes then I get the error that Mako tries to intepret the `this.index` variable as a Mako variable.

Comment: [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are using a JavaScript version prior to ECMAScript 2015 and thus string templates are not supported. You have to build the string on your own:

```
table.columns().every(function() {
    var that = this;
    $('#example thead input:nth(' + this.index() + ')').on('keyup change', function() {
        if (that.search() !== this.value) {
            that
                .search(this.value)
                .draw();
        }
    });
});
```

As Keith suggests in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46089130/1183192) you should use a transpiler like Babel. This gives you a lot of new functionalities and will make your life easier.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use new JS features in old browsers/JS engines your best bet is a transpiler like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).

This takes modern JS and recompiles it down to older versions, so you can target ES3 with ES2017 features.